# How to automate ODBC Data Source Administrator window in TestComplete

Tags: testcomplete

I need to automate the "doc" configuration in the ODBC Data Source Administrator window, but when I try to record it with Keyword record it doesn't capture what I previously set up.
Is there a way in testComplete to manipulating this type of object?

Comment: Hi Dimitrijie, welcome to stack overflow, please can you provide a reproducible example to better understand your problem.

Comment: Hi @ashwinagrawal

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. When I change the database with which i want to do the tests I change it with the ODBC Data Source Administrator. But Keyword Test Recording does not recognize or record anything what I do in the ODBC Data Source Administrator window. When I finiche, my Workspace is empty .

Comment: I suggest you look at doing this with command-line options instead.

Comment: TestComplete command line options would have no bearing on ODBC data sources. @DimitrijeScekic - are you testing Windows ODBC Data Source Administrator, or are you using a DB connection to provide data for testing another application?

Comment: I'm using a DB connection to provide data for testing another application.